# Ruby on Rails - Build time from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, parameters

I've this following params:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"sPoWmnLU984Py9BEIe8MgEVo8tqPsSdLznFZ0dITXAw=",
 "event"=>{"title"=>"",
 "description"=>"",
 "day"=>"2013-11-21",
 "start(1i)"=>"2013",
 "start(2i)"=>"11",
 "start(3i)"=>"25",
 "start(4i)"=>"07",
 "start(5i)"=>"00",
 "end(1i)"=>"2013",
 "end(2i)"=>"11",
 "end(3i)"=>"25",
 "end(4i)"=>"07",
 "end(5i)"=>"00",
 "day_id"=>"day"},
 "commit"=>"Event erstellen"}
```

and my controller:

```
start  = "#{params[:event][:start(4i)]}:#{params[:event][:start(5i)]}"
```

I want only the times attributes from the parameters, so that at the end i have something like this:

```
07:00
```

Comment: So, what's your question? Do you want to create a Time-instance with the data you have?

Comment: I want only the times attributes from the parameters, so that at the end i have something like this:

07:00

Comment: Do you have a `start` and `end` attribute (maybe virtually) in your model (assumed from your params)?

Comment: Looks like "start" is a DateTime attribute of the model. You could simply use the strftime method of DateTime to achieve this strftime("%H:%M")

Answer (score 0):

If "start" is a DateTime attribute of the model, you could simply use the strftime method of the dateTime. Something like start.strftime("%H:%M")